# TPersistent: Notification

Tags: delphi, components, delphi-xe3

I have a TPersistent defined as follows:

```
  TGlyph = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FOwner: TControl;
    FLayout: TGlyphAlignment;
    FVisible: Boolean;
    FImageIndex: Integer;
    FImages: TImageList;
    ..............
  protected
    procedure Invalidate;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TControl);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    .............
  published
    property ImageIndex: Integer read FImageIndex write SetImageIndex default -1;
    property Images: TImageList read FImages write SetImages;
    .............
  end;
```

Is it essential to have a notification procedures that assign nil value to FImages field, such as the kind you use for TComponent?

```
procedure TGlyph.Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation);
begin
  inherited;
  if (Operation = opRemove) and (AComponent = FImages) then
  begin
    FImages.OnChange := nil;
    FImages := nil;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;
```

if so, how should be written this procedure?

Thank you,
Enzo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TPersistent` does not support the `Notification()` system. You need `TComponent` for that.  If `TGlyph` is used inside of a `TComponent` that you have also written, then you can have that `TComponent` handle the notification and update `TGlyph` when needed. Otherwise, you will have to change `TGlyph` to derive from `TComponent`, in which case if `TGlyph` is used inside a `TComponent` then just be sure to have `TGlyph` call `SetSubComponent(True)` on itself to avoid any Object Inspector and DFM streaming issues.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer. I really appreciate your first solution, that has just been implemented and works fine!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your class is used. The `Notification` method is not called automatically, only by your own code (or code written by users of your class). So if `Notification` is never called there is no need in it.